# Writing data from equation solver to file over loop only outputs last 2 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I am trying to solve this problem of writing to a file, the time runs from 0 -> 1000 with increments of 100, however when I run the script, I keep getting only the final 2 elements of the output. I think there is an issue with the loop but I'm not sure. I would like for all of the data to be present from t=0 to t=1000 and not just the final 2 elements. You can see in the file, only t=900 and t=1000 are recorded. Can't seem to see what to change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd


plt.ion()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 8

P = 0      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
     Si = y[0]
     Zi = y[1]
     Ri = y[2]
     # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
     f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
     f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
     f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
     return [f0, f1, f2]

# initial conditions
S0 = 500.             # initial population
Z0 = 30                 # initial zombie population
R0 = 60                 # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]     # initial condition vector

#looping over some time instead of integrating in one go.
t_a = 0 
oput = 500
t_b = t_a + oput
delta_t = t_a + 100 
tend = 1000

dfs=[]
while t_a < tend: 

    t_c = t_a + delta_t 
    t=[t_a,t_c]
    y = odeint(f,y0,t,mxstep=10000) #Integrator
    t_a = t_c

    if(t_a > oput):
        t_b = t_b +oput

        S = y[:,0]
        R = y[:,1]
        Z = y[:,2]



dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'t': t, 'Z': Z,'R': R}))
g=pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
g.to_csv('example.csv',mode='w',index=False)
```

The other issue that arises is that I want to change my initial conditions to whatever the final element of the solver was with:

```
        S0 = S
        R0 = R
        Z0 = Z
        y0 = [S0,R0,Z0]
```

But I am met with this error:

```
ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.
```

How can I work around this error if I want to update the initial conditions with the pop values in the loop?

Comment: Do you want to write the result in the file during the computation (maybe because the computation is quite long)? or only at the end of the computation?

Comment: Is there any reason to perform a loop instead of passing a sequence of time instants to `odeint`?

Comment: Re _"I am met with this error"_ stuff: try placing a `print(y)` immediately after calling `odeint` (hint: `y_next_step = y[1]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only the last values because you do not output anything *during the loop execution* but just at the end of it.

To solve your problem, I'd go like this, leaving to `odeint` the task of looping over time steps,

```
In [21]: from scipy.integrate import odeint
In [22]: P, D, B, G, A = 0, 0.0001, 0.0095, 0.0001, 0.0001
In [23]: def fy(y, t):
    ...:      Si, Zi, Ri = y
    ...:      # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
    ...:      return P-B*Si*Zi-D*Si, B*Si*Zi+G*Ri-A*Si*Zi, D*Si+A*Si*Zi-G*Ri
In [24]: y0 = [500.0, 30.0, 60.0]
In [25]: res = odeint(fy, y0, [i*100.0 for i in range(11)], mxstep=1000)
In [26]: print('\n'.join(','.join('%+15.9f'%x for x in row) for row in res))
 +500.000000000,  +30.000000000,  +60.000000000
   +0.000000000, +525.356080701,  +64.643919299
   -0.000000000, +525.999298342,  +64.000701658
   +0.000000000, +526.636115893,  +63.363884107
   +0.000000000, +527.266597017,  +62.733402983
   +0.000000000, +527.890804714,  +62.109195286
   +0.000000000, +528.508801154,  +61.491198846
   +0.000000000, +529.120648555,  +60.879351445
   -0.000000000, +529.726408164,  +60.273591837
   -0.000000000, +530.326140479,  +59.673859521
   -0.000000000, +530.919905407,  +59.080094593
```

If you want to save a CSV format to a file, `print` supports redirection to an open file, like `print(..., file=open('res.txt'))`

Re *"I am met with this error"*, you never update (at least in the code you've shown) the values of the initial conditions, so that it's difficult to guess what went wrong, but I suppose that you used the like of `y0 = y`, while it should be `y0 = y[1]` — if you print `y` you'll understand why.

Finally, from  what I can understand, maybe your time step is a bit longer than what is desirable, as the live population at the end of the first time step is 0 (more precisely, `2.72457580e-13`) and it is possible that you want to follow the process rather than look at its final result.

---

**Addendum**

As a follow-up to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567086/writing-data-from-equation-solver-to-file-over-loop-only-outputs-last-2-elements?noredirect=1#comment90108756_51570241), you can loop over the results, examine them and take appropriate actions, e.g.

```
res = odeint(...)

for S, R, Z in res:
    output_style = 0
    if S<40 and R> 30 : output_style = 1 
    elif ............ : output_style = 2
    ....
    output(S, R, Z, output_style)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The reason I used a loop is because later I want to include some conditions, so for example if R <= 55 to write a new, different file with just the results of R. Do you know if this would be possible with the method you've outlined as it seems a lot simpler than the loop I used?

Comment: In `def f(...` you unpack `y` into `Si, Zi , Ri` but later you unpack it into `S, R, Z`... I don't know why you _**changed the order of unpacking**_ but it seems, at least, suspicious

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, you're right, that's something I need to look into. I will implement these accordingly, not sure why I thought looping over the time was a good idea.